# Having a simple python issue with a game I created

Tags: python

I was making this simple python game where you guess a random number. I was wondering how you would loop it so it would keep going until you get the correct number. It needs to do that without changing the number while the player is guessing.

```
import random
print('Welcome to Guess The Number V1.0')
print('the rules are simple guess a number 1-6 and see if youre correct')
number = random.randint(0,7)
#------------------------------------------------------
guess = int(input('Enter a number:'))
print(guess)
#------------------------------------------------------
if guess > number:
  print('Your guess was to high')
if guess < number:
  print('Your guess was to low')
#-------------------------------------------------------
if guess == number:
  print('Correct!')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Fist and foremost, post your code in the question: not a link, not an image; post the code as properly formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

If you used a while loop you could make it run without needing to stop it and reload the site. it would look like this

```
while guess != number:
    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess was to high')
    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess was to low')
    #-------------------------------------------------------
    if guess == number:
        print('Correct!')
```

Comment: Not totally correct though but the answer from Jono 2906 is correct

Answer (score 0):

You would use a `while` loop to repeat the guessing procedure like so:

```
import random
print('Welcome to Guess The Number V1.0')
print('the rules are simple guess a number 1-6 and see if youre correct')
number = random.randint(0,7)
#------------------------------------------------------
guess = int(input('Enter a number:'))

while guess != number: #Following code only runs if the guess isn't correct
    if guess > number:
      print('Your guess was to high')
    if guess < number:
      print('Your guess was to low')

    guess = int(input('Enter a number:')) #Need this here to ask for another guess
                                          #and avoid an infinite loop


print('Correct!')
```

Hope that helps!